# ListeningExector has a variable number of ListenableFuture, need to know when all are complete

Tags: java, guava

I have a REST API from which I need to pull a hierarchy of data in the following shape:

```
- Grandparents
  - Parents
    - Children
```

The initial call fetches a list of all the Grandparents:

```
Futures.addCallback(loadGrandparents(), processGrandparents());
```

Then for each Grandparent (independently from the other Grandparents), I need to fetch all Parents. This is the `processGrandparents()` code:

```
return new FutureCallback<List<Grandparents>>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(List<Grandparents> grandparents) {

         for(grandparent g : grandparents) {
             Futures.addCallback(loadParents(g), 
                                 processParents());
         }
     }
}
```

Finally, for each Parent (again independently) I need to fetch the Children, so this is the `processParents()` code:

```
return new FutureCallback<List<Parents>>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(List<Parents> parents) {

         for(parent p : parents) {
             Futures.addCallback(loadChildren(p), 
                                 processChildren());
         }
     }
}
```

Finally, in the `processChildren()` call there is some data handling but no further Futures.

I am using ListenableFutures for this with a ListeningExecutor which works quite well, the threading is neatly handled. The issue I have is that I don't know when all the chains have completed so I can say 'My REST update is now completed'.

I haven't seen any examples that let me somehow check everything. Am I 'chaining' these callbacks incorrectly? Adding a listener to the top ListenableFuture triggers almost immediately, so it seems it's not awaiting the completion of callbacks I added deeper down.

An example of the load code is as follows (they all follow the same pattern):

```
private ListenableFuture<List<Grandparent>> loadGrandparents() {
    // The executor is from MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator
    // The ApiCall is a Callable implementation doing a HTTP call  
    return executor.submit(new ApiCall("path-to-fetch-grandparents"));
}
```

Comment: FYI, I am working around this currently by using an `AtomicInteger` that I increment whenever I am about to fire a REST request and decrement at the end of the processing function. This works but it seems wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for [`whenAllComplete`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#whenAllComplete-java.lang.Iterable-)?

Comment: I've not been able to use that @LouisWasserman because it expects the type to be the same, and it actually gathers all the outcomes together which I do not want (it would be very memory intensive, the data is being piped onward).

Comment: what makes you conclude that it gathers the outcomes together?  You just write `whenAllComplete(futures).doThis(...)`, and it doesn't matter if all the futures actually have the same type, because you can just use `Futures.<Object>whenAllComplete(...).call(...)`.

Comment: Keen to understand how that might work.  I'd somehow need to collate all the Futures I create together in a List of Futures, but then I still have the problem of not knowing when the list is done, so when and where can I call `whenAllComplete`. I.e. part of my issue is that the `futures` you have in your example is of undetermined length (it depends on how much data comes out of the remote API), and each lower level call spawns more Futures depending on how many objects are returned.